# How to avoid duplication in VSCode intellisense when exporting defaults?

Tags: javascript, typescript, export, svelte, es6-modules

I have a directory structure like so:

- `lib/assets/thing/index.ts`
- `lib/assets/thing/stuff/A.svelte`
- `lib/assets/thing/stuff/B.svelte`
- `lib/assets/thing/stuff/C.svelte`
- `lib/assets/thing/stuff/D.svelte`

One of these `thing/stuff` files is just a normal component with markup.

In `index.ts` i have:

```
export { default as A } from './stuff/A.svelte';
export { default as B } from './stuff/B.svelte';
export { default as C } from './stuff/C.svelte';
export { default as D } from './stuff/D.svelte';
```

This way from elsewhere I can import like:

```
import { A, B, C, D } from '$lib/assets/thing';
```

rather than:

```
import A from '$lib/assets/thing/stuff/A.svelte';
import B from '$lib/assets/thing/stuff/B.svelte';
// .etc
```

The only issue is that VSCode intellisense will show 2 results when auto-completing `A`, one from `$lib/assets/thing` and one from `$lib/assets/thing/stuff/A.svelte`. Without resorting to a vscode setting like `typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns`, is there a way to structure my asset folder to avoid the suggestion in the `thing/stuff` folder?

Comment: How about not using a barrel file? Sure your imports a bit longer but also more explicit with other potential beneficial tradeoffs (like no vscode dupes).